# Make MenuStrip look like MainMenu

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, menu, styling

When it comes to GUI, I decided that any optical changes to the default windows style could make my application look worse. A good looking MainMenu is way better than a bad looking VS2012 / Office2010 MenuStrip.

the `MainMenu` has some disatvantages over the MenuStrip. The main concern here is that you can't use images.

The question is: Is there a way to make MenuStrip and ContextMenuStrip look just like MainMenu and ContextMenu (System default look)?

Comment: Have you tried changing the `MenuStrip.RenderMode` property to `System` (or some other value)? If it helps, I can repost it as an answer.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but it doesn't apply the Vista/7 theme, but only the XP theme instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change Menu hover color - WINFORMS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260303/how-to-change-menu-hover-color-winforms)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, as I don't want to render a custom menu. I want to use the built in menu in Vista/Windows 7.

Comment: The problem is that MS took the decision at some point that a MenuStrip is rendered by .NET rather than the OS, so that your program looks the same on the development machine as it will on the customers. This has many advantages, and is generally considered a good thing. This is one of those disadvantages. Use a custom drawn MainMenu and add images if you really want to.

Comment: Isn't there a way using `RenderMode = System` to set the basic layout and then apply some UXTheme stuff? I tried `SetWindowsTheme(..., "Explorer")` but it had no effect.