# Applying a background image to a Menustrip submenu Item

Tags: c#, winforms, background, controls, menustrip

I have created this form and a custom function that paints the background of the control with a darkened piece of the forms background.

[image]

On hover the control area is highlighted, Is there an accessor to this color? Like menustrip.Highlight Color?

[image]

I have been unable to find the accessor for the sub menus as well. I have looked on msdn and have found articles on the ability to change the entire theme, color only, no information on how to set a background image. I have searched SO and found similar topics but none that answer my question or close enough to extrapolate the correct answer. Any assistance would be greatly appriciated. Written in C#. Also, is the submenu a added to the list of controls when it exists?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change Menu hover color - WINFORMS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260303/how-to-change-menu-hover-color-winforms)

Comment: I am not attempting to change any color. I am attempting to apply a background image to the

Comment: The color name is Color.Transparent.

Answer (score 2):

You should use ToolStripRenderer to customize menu look. Assign renderer to menu and call invalidate:

```
menuStrip.Renderer = new ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(new DarkColorTable());
menuStrip.Invalidate();
```

As you can see, renderer requires color table. You should create custom one and override all colors you want to customize:

```
public class DarkColorTable : ProfessionalColorTable
{
    public override Color MenuStripGradientBegin
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Black); }
    }

    public override Color MenuStripGradientEnd
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Black); }
    }

    public override Color ButtonSelectedHighlight
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(64, Color.Black); }
    }

    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Private Sub BackImageToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BackImageToolStripMenuItem.Click
 Me.MenuStrip1.BackgroundImage=Form1.My.Resources.Resources.nature 'where nature is image name
    BackImageToolStripMenuItem.Checked = True
End Sub
```