# Visual Studio 2010 menu strip colors

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, menubar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change Menu hover color - WINFORMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260303/how-to-change-menu-hover-color-winforms)

I'm customizing my menu strip colors. I would like to make it look like the one in Visual Studio 2010.

[image: VS 2010 menu strip]

Is a there an existing document where colors are referenced?

**EDIT**
I know how to use a custom renderer to change the colors. My question goal is to get a list of all colors. I could use a image editor software to find the RGB values of each color with the color picker tool, but I was wondering if the list of colors is written somewhere:

- `MenuStripForeColor`
- `MenuStripGradientBegin`
- `MenuStripGradientEnd`
- `MenuItemPressedGradientBegin`
- `MenuItemPressedGradientMiddle`
- `MenuItemPressedGradientEnd`
- `MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin`
- `MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd`
- `MenuItemSelected`
- `MenuBorder`
- `MenuItemBorder`
- `ImageMarginGradientBegin`
- `ImageMarginGradientMiddle`
- `ImageMarginGradientEnd`
- `ToolStripDropDownBackground`
- ... others (?)

Comment: What do you mean by color? the background color of menustripitem or the colors in the  ImageList you mean?

Comment: @MohsenAfshin: The background/foreground colors of the menu, the menu items...

Comment: VS2010 uses WPF, it is not a MenuStrip.  The full list is available as the properties of the ProfessionalColorTable class.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio uses WPF. But, you can achieve similar effect if you use `MainMenu` instead of `MenuStrip`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use your own renderer to achieve this... 
A custom renderer is discussed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229725.aspx