# Is there a way to change the menustrips hover highlight color?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, gdi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change Menu hover color - WINFORMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260303/how-to-change-menu-hover-color-winforms)

When using a menustrip in .net when you hover it, it adds a blue highlight overtop of it. So I am wondering if it is possible to change the highlight color to a different colour/style?

I am geussing you could override it using the OnPaint() method, but I have no idea where to go from there.

I am using vb.net and WinForms.

Comment: @bluefeet I just finished writing my code, ready to post an answer, and then I see you found a duplicate answer. :( *sad face*

Comment: That is in C#. I made it clear I am using vb.net

Comment: C# and VB.NET are very alike. Nothing difficult about it to translate.