# Manipulating menu strip font colors in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, colors, windows-forms-designer, menustrip

I'm building a program on which I'm hoping to have a black background and white text.

---

I've tried setting the background color to black, the forecolor/font color to white, but during highlight I want two different colors and another two during while clicked. I can't find the proper way to manipulate the properties. Has anyone else ever tried this?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change Menu hover color - WINFORMS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260303/how-to-change-menu-hover-color-winforms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to do this using the link attached at the top of this one. However, the resources I had to dig out around it lead me to believe this deserves to stand as its own question.

### What I did

I went onto my `MainForm` and inserted the following code (as per the suggested solution):

```
public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        menuStripMain.Renderer = new MyRenderer();
    }

    private class MyRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
    {
        public MyRenderer() : base(new MyColors()) { }
    }

    private class MyColors : ProfessionalColorTable
    {
        public override Color MenuItemSelected
        {
            get { return Color.White; }
        }
        public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin
        {
            get { return Color.Black; }
        }
        public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd
        {
            get { return Color.SlateGray; }
        }
        public override Color MenuItemBorder
        {
            get { return Color.Yellow; }
        }
    }
```

However, as you can see, there are properties that are not included in the solution. The parts that you want to manipulate here can be made to work for **any object on your form, not just the menu strip**, the reference names for which you can access [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ProfessionalColors_properties.aspx). In addition, there is a large collection of colors with odd names that can be addressed, the list for which is right [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors.aspx). I don't think you can use hex color codes.

This way you can completely customize the colors of any object in your form!