# How to change the background color of a menustripitem in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, background, menustrip

**Hello**

*This picture sums it up:* [image]

Got some troubles, couldn't find a proper answer using the search bar. I've tried to use a custom Render, but it is always just for professional render, when I'm using System Render for the menustrip.

Edit: Found out myself

```
public class CustomColorTable : ProfessionalColorTable
{
    public override Color MenuItemSelected
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(51,153,255); }
    }

    public override Color ToolStripDropDownBackground
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(83, 83, 83); }
    }

    public override Color ImageMarginGradientBegin
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(83, 83, 83); }
    }

    public override Color ImageMarginGradientEnd
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(83, 83, 83); }
    }

    public override Color ImageMarginGradientMiddle
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(83,83,83); }
    }

    public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(51, 153, 255); }
    }
    public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(51, 153, 255); }
    }

    public override Color MenuItemPressedGradientBegin
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(51, 153, 255); }
    }

    public override Color MenuItemPressedGradientMiddle
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(51, 153, 255); }
    }

    public override Color MenuItemPressedGradientEnd
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(51, 153, 255); }
    }

    public override Color MenuItemBorder
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(51, 153, 255); }

    }
}
```

and then just use the new colortable with:

```
MS1.Renderer = new ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(new CustomColorTable()); ;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change Menu hover color - WINFORMS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260303/how-to-change-menu-hover-color-winforms)

Comment: have you checked this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29497/Custom-Rendering-for-the-ToolStrip-MenuStrip-and-S

Comment: I've followed your example using the CustomColorTable to control most of the colors on a ToolStrip with an OverFlow menu, but for some reason it ignores my custom table when the buttons show up in the overflow. Any ideas why?