# winforms toolstripmenuitem how to stop inverting color?

Tags: c#, winforms

I set the background and foreground colors like this:

```
    this.loadToolStripMenuItem.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkBlue;
    this.loadToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
    this.loadToolStripMenuItem.Name = "loadToolStripMenuItem";
    this.loadToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(152, 22);
    this.loadToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Load";
    this.loadToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.loadDatabase_Click);
```

However, at run time when the ToolStripMenuItem is selected the color scheme changes such that the background is a white/grey color. Mixed with yellow this is a bad appearance.

How does one control the background and foreground color while the item is being selected with the mouse? Ideally, I would like to keep DarkBlue and Yellow and have no change in appearance when the mouse is selecting the item.

Comment: Create your own renderer so you can change [its color table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9260827/17034).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767478/color-change-for-menuitem/36768361#36768361