# Color change for MenuItem

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, menustrip, toolstripmenu

I am programming a Backup Tool. On top of my tool I have a menustrip containing two toolstripmenuitems. I changed the colors a little bit to my expectations. Not focused the menu looks great:

[image: Unclicked Menu Item]

When I now click on the menu item "File" to open the context menu, the color changes to white and I am not able to read the text anymore:

[image: Clicked Menu Item]

Can anyone please tell me where I can change that behavior? I use Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, Windows Forms Application, Code is in C#.

Here is the code:

`//
    // initializing menuStrip1
    // 
    this.menuStrip1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.MediumBlue;
    this.menuStrip1.BackgroundImageLayout = 
        System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Center;
    this.menuStrip1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI Semilight", 
        15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular,

        System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
    this.menuStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this.fileToolStripMenuItem,
        this.helpToolStripMenuItem});
    this.menuStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.menuStrip1.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 40);
    this.menuStrip1.Name = "menuStrip1";
    this.menuStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1056, 40);
    this.menuStrip1.TabIndex = 77;
    this.menuStrip1.Text = "menuStrip1";
    // 
    // initializing fileToolStripMenuItem and adding to menuStrip1
    // 
    this.fileToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(new 
        System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
    this.saveToolStripMenuItem,
    this.saveAsToolStripMenuItem,
    this.loadToolStripMenuItem});
    this.fileToolStripMenuItem.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri Light", 
        15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, 
        System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
    this.fileToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = 
        System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
    this.fileToolStripMenuItem.Name = "fileToolStripMenuItem";
    this.fileToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(54, 36);
    this.fileToolStripMenuItem.Text = "File";
    this.fileToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler
        (this.fileToolStripMenuItem_Click);
    // 
    // initializing saveToolStripMenuItem and adding to fileToolStripMenuItem
    // 
    this.saveToolStripMenuItem.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.MediumBlue;
    this.saveToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = 
        System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
    this.saveToolStripMenuItem.Name = "saveToolStripMenuItem";
    this.saveToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(166, 30);
    this.saveToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Save";
    this.saveToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler
        (this.saveToolStripMenuItem_Click);`
//

Comment: Can you post your color customization code?

Comment: Added the initializing code :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default this feature is not available out of the box. You need to create a custom `Renderer` for you tool strip to achieve this.

Create a class that inherits from `ToolStripProfessionalRenderer` -

```
    private class BlueRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnRenderMenuItemBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, e.Item.Size);
            Color c = Color.MediumBlue;
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(c))
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rc);
        }
    }
```

And attach this renderer to your menu strip in your form constructor -

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        menuStrip1.Renderer = new BlueRenderer();
    }
```

Comment: Haha, works fine, thank you very much! Funny that you can change all colors by default but not that specific one... Microsoft logic?!

Comment: One further question. Now the Color is MediumBlue for all states. Can I have LightBlue when I clicked the item in menuStrip1?

Comment: @schmelzer-daniel - Just define your clocr like this: `Color c = e.Item.Selected ? Color.LightBlue : Color.MediumBlue; `

Answer (score 15):

You can create your own `ProfessionalColorTable` and override it's properties:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
     public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
         public Form1()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
             menuStrip1.Renderer = new ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(new MyColorTable());
         }
     }

     public class MyColorTable : ProfessionalColorTable
     {
         public override Color ToolStripDropDownBackground
         {
             get
             {
                 return Color.Blue;
             }
         }

         public override Color ImageMarginGradientBegin
         {
             get
             {
                 return Color.Blue;
             }
         }

         public override Color ImageMarginGradientMiddle
         {
             get
             {
                 return Color.Blue;
             }
         }

         public override Color ImageMarginGradientEnd
         {
             get
             {
                 return Color.Blue;
             }
         }

         public override Color MenuBorder
         {
             get
             {
                 return Color.Black;
             }
         }

         public override Color MenuItemBorder
         {
             get
             {
                 return Color.Black;
             }
         }

         public override Color MenuItemSelected
         {
             get
             {
                 return Color.Navy;
             }
         }

         public override Color MenuStripGradientBegin
         {
             get
             {
                 return Color.Blue;
             }
         }

         public override Color MenuStripGradientEnd
         {
             get
             {
                 return Color.Blue;
             }
         }

         public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin
         {
             get
             {
                 return Color.Navy;
             }
         }

         public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd
         {
             get
             {
                 return Color.Navy;
             }
         }

         public override Color MenuItemPressedGradientBegin
         {
             get
             {
                 return Color.Blue;
             }
         }

         public override Color MenuItemPressedGradientEnd
         {
             get
             {
                 return Color.Blue;
             }
         }
     }
}
```

This is result of code above:

[image: Custom menu]

Comment: This is actually more straightforward and readable - having the colors in a separate class is handy.

Comment: This is a beautiful result :) Works great +1