# Change All ToolStripMenuItem ForeColor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, colors, items, menustrip

I'm trying to change the color from every Item from the menu Strip, but the dropdown items I can't change.The dropdown menu items aren't white the way I want. My need is to change the ForeColor from every item with one code in the .cs file.

Comment: The related codes should be provided to help you out.

Comment: There is no code to chance every ForeColor at once. not that i can find

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: [Change the color table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9260827/17034)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pertinent to your rather broad question, the sort of generic answer is: `ToolStripMenuItem` controls (e.g. _`mnuItem` ) have `ForeColor` property, which can be set programmatically in C# code-behind, like: `_mnuItem .ForeColor = Color.Black`;

Hope this may help.