# MenuStrip Selected Color

Tags: c#, winforms, menustrip

I have looked into all search results from StackOverflow to no avail, including: [How to change menu hover color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260303/how-to-change-menu-hover-color-winforms)

I have a menu strip which is black with white font color.  When you select it the font stays white but the box turns white too.  How do i set the "selected" back color of a menu item?

By "selected" i mean you clicked on the menu option. NOT hover.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ProfessionalColorTable(v=vs.110).aspx

I checked this out but none of these targeted the top tier menu item.

[image]

```
    private class MyRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
    {
        public MyRenderer() : base(new MyColors()) { }
    }

    private class MyColors : ProfessionalColorTable
    {
        public override Color ToolStripDropDownBackground
        {
            get { return Color.Black; }
        }
        public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin
        {
            get { return Color.Gray; }
        }
        public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd
        {
            get { return Color.Red; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Use MenuItemPressedGradientBegin / End instead of MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin / End to change the color of the "primary" bar.

```
Menu.Renderer = new MyRenderer();

private class MyRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    public MyRenderer() : base(new MyColors()) { }
}

private class MyColors : ProfessionalColorTable
{
    public override Color MenuItemPressedGradientBegin
    {
        get { return Color.Gray; }
    }

    public override Color MenuItemPressedGradientEnd
    {
        get { return Color.Red; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer proves that the claim "I checked this out but none of these targeted the top tier menu item." in your question was false.