# Use different Highlight color for different ToolStripMenuItems

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, menustrip, toolstripmenu

There is one ToolStripMenuItem object which is containing other 3 ToolStripMenuItems on dropdown. I want use different hightlight colors on MouseHover of different ToolStripMenuItems. Say, For Yes - Green. For No - Red. For MayBe - Blue. The color of highlight should get change accordingly as i move among different items. Please help.

P.S. - MouseEnter, MouseLeave, MouseHover events aren't working because they work on ToolStripMenuItems and it is the case of **Highlighter**.

Comment: Here is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9260827/5753992) regarding to 'How to change menu hover color?'

Comment: @LarsTech The linked post is not duplicate at all. The OP wants to use **different Highlight color for different ToolStripMenuItems**. The linked post doesn't satisfy such requirement and provides a way to change highlight color for all items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using a `ToolStripProfessionalRenderer`, changing back color doesn't change highlight color. Also while your tool strip uses a single renderer, since the renderer uses `MenuItemSelectedColor` property of  `ProfessionalColorTable` of renderer, it can't render highlight color based on a condition.

You can change renderer of `ToolStrip` dynamically and set it's renderer to a renderer which draws highlight in your desired color.

[image]

Here are the steps which I used:

**(1)** Set the `RenderMode` of your `ToolStrip` to `ManagerRenderMode`:

```
this.toolStrip1.RenderMode = ToolStripRenderMode.ManagerRenderMode;
```

**(2)** Create a custom color table which you can pass `MenuItemSelectedColor` to it:

```
public class MyColorTable : ProfessionalColorTable
{
    private Color menuItemSelectedColor;
    public MyColorTable(Color color): base()
    {
        menuItemSelectedColor = color;
    }
    public override Color MenuItemSelected
    {
        get { return menuItemSelectedColor; }
    }
}
```

**(3)** Define renderers which you need at form level:

```
ToolStripProfessionalRenderer r = 
    new ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(new MyColorTable(Color.Red));
ToolStripProfessionalRenderer g = 
    new ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(new MyColorTable(Color.Green));
ToolStripProfessionalRenderer b = 
    new ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(new MyColorTable(Color.Blue));
```

**(4)** Handle `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` event for all your menu items which you want to use custom renderer and assign this handlers to all of them:

```
private void menuItem_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
    if (item.Text == "Yes")
        ToolStripManager.Renderer = g;
    else if (item.Text == "No")
        ToolStripManager.Renderer = r;
    else if (item.Text == "MayBe")
        ToolStripManager.Renderer = b;
    else
        ToolStripManager.Renderer = null; // or use your default renderer
}

private void menuItem_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripManager.Renderer = null; // or use your default renderer
}
```

Comment: This solution works, But the problem now is - That if i am going from first dropdown to second, and then second to third. Now in third dropdown only, I want this functionality while it is highlighting all the other dropdowns.

Comment: So, The problem actually lies in Nested MenuItems. I don't want to highlight the parent items.

Comment: The link of image is broken. But pay attention to handle enter and leave events only for those items which you need the behavior and not for all items.