# Windows Forms MenuStrip Border Color

Tags: c#, forms, menustrip

I am making app in Windows Forms. I've added MenuStrip and changed it colors using ToolStripProfessionalRenderer. The problem is that whenever I am trying to change dropdown border color it only changes the outside border ( image below ).
[image]

How can I change the remaining white border that still is visible inside? Or how to just disable border there?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to override properties that you need to set the color.
This [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstriprenderer(v=VS.90).aspx) will help you to do that.

And this is another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260303/how-to-change-menu-hover-color) about how to implement your class

HK

Comment: I've already done that. The problem is when I am trying to set color in MenuBorder which should be responsible for menustrip border it only changes the outside border. I cannnot figure out how to change the white border visible at my image.