# Changing color of stripmenu on hover

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2017

I've created a menustrip and when I select it, by default it turns white. Is it possible to change that color? Here's some prints of my menu.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change menu hover color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260303/how-to-change-menu-hover-color)

Comment: That way dont work for me