# How to remove horizontal grey line between Toolstrips?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to configure 3 toolstrips but it seems they show a grey horizontal line between them.

I've researched a bit and I only found a solution for the white border of the toolstrip items by overriding OnRenderToolStripBorder.

I've did that already but I still keep with my issue here. I've attached an image so anyone can try to help me.`

```
public class ToolStripOverride : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    public ToolStripOverride() { }

    protected override void OnRenderToolStripBorder(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

+

```
        this.toolStrip1.Renderer = new ToolStripOverride();
```

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Did you set your render mode? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-custom-draw-a-toolstrip-control

Comment: WinForms or WPF? Please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: WinForms.

And yes I'm setting the render mode in Designer for the 3 toolstrips.

Description updated

Comment: You are supposed to actually render the border, you can't leave it unpainted.  Simplest way is to change the border color so it matches the background, assuming it isn't a gradient.  ToolStripBorderColor property: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9260827/17034

Comment: @HansPassant I'm having difficulty with that guide. Is there any other options, using the code I applied already?

Comment: @HansPassant update: I was able to implement it but didn't work

Comment: I managed to fix according to the both solutions!

Thank you @HansPassant