# Disable ToolStripMenuItem highlight without losing background

Tags: c#, background-image, menustrip, toolstripmenu

So I have a `MenuStrip` with a couple of `ToolStripMenuItem`s. Two of my `ToolStripMenuItem` components are having a background image (battery icon and shutdown icon).

Now I want to disable the default `MenuStrip` mouse hover effect (that blueish background) for the `ToolStripMenuItem` elements which I have set a background. To achieve this I have override the `OnRenderMenuItemBackground` event implementation, like this:

```
internal class NoHighlightRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnRenderMenuItemBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.OwnerItem != null)
            {
                base.OnRenderMenuItemBackground(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

And use this custom renderer for my `MenuStrip` like this:

```
myMenuStrip.Renderer = new NoHighlightRenderer();
```

This works fine for the elements that don't have a background image set. For the ones with the background set, the background image will not show.

I want the background image to be visible, how to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260303/how-to-change-menu-hover-color

Comment: @HansPassant Well I tried to override `MenuItemSelected`, `MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin`, and `MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd` to `Color.Transparent`, but that didn't what I need. Any other ideas?